# Getting indexOf() to search just name and not whole element

Tags: javascript

I have tried lots of different things over the past 2 days and i cannot get this to work how i want it to.

https://jsfiddle.net/9wc0bjn7/2/

```
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }

  }
}
```

for some reason it doesn't work at all in JSFiddle but on my internal code it works and searches the whole  element.

I want it to only search the id=name element and not the whole  element, otherwise when someone types "Ext" it brings everyone up...

Thanks

Lee

Comment: It works in your fiddle when you define your function in the document's head section. Just click on the settings icon on the JavaScript frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do the trick: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e51rrso4/1/)

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, n, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    n = li[i].querySelector("#name");
  if (!n) continue;
    if (n.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }

  }
}
document.querySelector('#myInput').addEventListener('keyup',myFunction)
```

```css
#myInput {
  background-image: url('/images/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px;
  /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a.header {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  cursor: default;
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#" class="header">A</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <div style="float: left;padding-right: 20px;">
        <p id="name"><b>Aimee Smith</b></p>
        <p id="f14">Accounts Payroll</p>
        <br><b>Ext:</b> 670
        <p><b>eMail:</b> aimee.smith@domain.com</p>
      </div>

      <div style="float: none; clear: both;"></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="header">B</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="header">C</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="header">D</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="header">E</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="header">F</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="header">G</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="header">H</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="header">I</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="header">J</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="header">K</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="header">L</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <div style="float: left;padding-right: 20px;">
        <p id="name"><b>Lee Smith</b></p>
        <p id="f14">IT Support</p>
        <br><b>Ext:</b> 676
        <p><b>eMail:</b> lee.smith@domain.com</p>
      </div>
      <div style="float: none; clear: both;"></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="header">M</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <div style="float: left;padding-right: 20px;">
        <p id="name"><b>Mark Smith</b></p>
        <p id="f14">IT Manager</p>
        <br><b>Ext:</b> 666
        <p><b>eMail:</b> mark.smith@domain.com</p>
      </div>
      <div style="float: none; clear: both;"></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="header">N</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="header">O</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="header">P</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="header">Q</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="header">R</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="header">S</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="header">T</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="header">U</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="header">V</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="header">W</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="header">X</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="header">Y</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="header">Z</a></li>
</ul>
```

Another thing is - if you want to hide labels too.

Comment: thats brill it does kind of do what i need, but yeah it doesn't hide labels any more whereas my original code did

Comment: How about that? [forked fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vucjv5h6/1/) Little more complex, but I'm afraid it's necessary.

Comment: that did the same didn't return the labels

Answer (score 0):

You can be more selective about what you search for. You are searching the entire A element whereas you should be selecting the first

in the .

querySelector will return the first matching element:

```
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].querySelector("a p");
    if (a && a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
```

See...
https://jsfiddle.net/e2trzpqL/1/

Comment: this is 99%  there.. however when you delete the text the labels are still gone..